# Java - how to set class name in generic class from String?

Tags: java, string, class

know You, what i can set class name in generic from string?
Ex.:

```
ExClass<Integer, AnyClass_nameFromString > = new ExClass();
```

Where AnyClass is class name from string ex. Integer, Double, String etc.
I don't know, what set the class name in parameters for generic <> (what make classNameFromString as class name)..

```
Class.forName(nameFromString)
```

doesn't work:(
I must set this class name before create object. I cant write
ExClass
because i want this for TableView new TableColumn. When I set new TableColumn, solumn is not sorted..

It's possible in Java?

Comment: `AnyClass<Integer, String>`?

Comment: Are those dynamically created classes in any way related? E.g. share a common supper class or interface, then you could just delcare it as `AnyClass<Integer, CommonSuper>`

Comment: What you want to do is impossible; you don't know the name until runtime, but you need to know it at compile time. See how this is impossible? You would need to be able to predict the future to do that... That is not possible in Java nor in any other programming language.

Comment: Sorry.. I dont must know name before compile. I must know this name before create object:):)

Comment: @aaa where do you get that name?

Comment: If you know the type at compile time, you don't need to be looking it up at runtime with `forName`

Comment: Type will be set at runtime

Comment: Then you can't set it at compile time. See my answer as to one option which might help you.

Comment: I have a list of types, and type wil be selected in runtime

Comment: Types are Integer, Double, String, Date etc...

Answer (score 1):

Generics are a compile time check. If you don't know the type at compile time, you can use `Object` or `?` as at runtime this is what it will be anyway.

If you know a common ancestor of all the classes you might want, you can use that common ancestor.

Say the type has to be comparable, you could assume the common ancestor is `Comparable`

```
ExClass<Integer, Comparable> = new ExClass<>();
```

Comment: @aaa if you know the class has to be `Comparable`, you can make it Comparable.